# How can I press a key of the keyboard from my application?

Tags: qt

E.g. I receive the character 'w' from serial communication and my application must press the key "W", like if the application were able to write like user does with the keyboard.

I was able to do this with class Robot in Java (e.g. Robot.press (KEY_ENTER), if a press a button the application will write a letter or a word, but with Qt Creator I haven't found a way to do it.

I've tried with this code but it's simulating a key was pressed, not pressing the key as I need.

```
QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Enter, Qt::NoModifier);
QCoreApplication::postEvent(receiver, event);
```

Comment: FYI, Qt Creator is an IDE. If you search for things including the "creator" word, you're unlikely to find what you wish for, since the IDE is not Qt. The name of the framework is Qt :)

Comment: This is a duplicate unless you wish to be sending keypresses to *other* applications. In that case, Qt won't help you, and you'll need platform-specific approaches. On Linux, the simplest would be to use evdev by writing to `/dev/input`. On Windows, you could start with [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput)

Comment: This might be also interesting to you: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdbus-index.html